# selecting hidden span

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Trying to select span within the first item in a usorted list but I can't quite seem to get the DOM right

```
    <li class="chapterItem"> <a
    href="http://www.neuromanga.com/mangaReader.php?chapterNo=12&amp;#pageNo=1"
    title="http://www.neuromanga.com/mangaReader.php?chapterNo=12&amp;#pageNo=1
    ">Naruto 522 world</a> <span
    id="date">Nov 21st 2010</span> <br>
    <span style="display:none"
    class="hiddenChapNo">12</span> </li>
```

Here is the jQuery code I been trying to use to select it

```
alert($('li').first().$('.hiddenChapNo').text());
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [`.find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/) to get a descendant here, like this:

```
alert($('li').first().find('.hiddenChapNo').text());
```

Or a bit more compact with [`:first`](http://api.jquery.com/first-selector/) and a [descendant selector](http://api.jquery.com/descendant-selector/) (space):

```
alert($('li:first .hiddenChapNo').text());
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code certainly looks like it should work, I assume that there's another `<li>` before this one that trips it up.

Also, ids are (should be) unique in a web page, so `$('#hiddenChapNo')` should be sufficient.

Assuming you need multiple hidden spans, the proper way to mark them would be `<span class="hiddenChapNo">` (you can then also hide them with CSS instead of inline styles).

Comment: I changed it to class and that is the very first item in the unsorted list but despite that it still isn't sending out the alert

Comment: Try testing without the `<br>`, and also try with `alert($('.hiddenChapNo').text());`

Answer (score 0):

Try just using `alert($('#hiddenChapNo').text());`. An `id` should be unique on a page, use classes if you need otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
alert($('.hiddenChapNo').first().text());
```